# Deploy Release in Azure Devops from a logic app

Tags: azure, azure-devops, virtual-machine, azure-logic-apps

We have created a pipeline to restart multiple VM services in correct order. Within Azure Logic App I can create a release, but want to deploy the same release daily. How can I do this in Logic Apps?

I current use logic apps to shutdown and start VMs daily as they are not used during silent hours but need to deploy restart services pipeline regularly.

From the picture you can see it only creates release not deploys it. I need it to only deploy to CL04 stage daily not all three stages and really don't need a new release every day, just redeploy release 7 to the same environment that the start VM logic app is running on daily.
[image]

Comment: Another thought I might me able to Send an HTTP request to Azure DevOps but cannot find a rest API to deploy

Answer (score -1):

> but want to deploy the same release daily.

*You can achieve this if you use **Recurrence Trigger** in your Logic app workflow.*

[image]

[image]

*For complete information you can go through this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-recurrence).*

Comment: The reoccurrence I can understand and have that in the start/stop logic app it is "deploy a release" part in particular picking a release and a stage and that I need help with as the create release is well documented.